# how to pass parameters to a method containing lambda code block

Tags: kotlin, lambda, max

In one of the edifying Kotlin tutorials for lambda functions, the folowing code snippet was used:

```
 max(s : String, { a, b -> b.length > a.length })
```

To learn how to do it, I coded it in two different ways. However, neither of them is working and the follwoing error is generated:

> Annotation is required on each parameter

I tried to code it as a function.

```
fun max(s : String, { a, b -> b.length > a.length }) : String {
    return ""
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How are the parameter `a` and `b` passed?
2. How do I write the above max function in Kotlin correctly

Comment: Could you share the tutorial you were following?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you mean:

```
fun max(s: String, predicate: (a: String, b: String) -> Boolean) : String {
    return "" // don’t know how to do this, what is the required function?
}
```